# libgdx Align text on selectbox

Tags: java, android, libgdx, dropdownbox

I´m trying to align the text of the selectbox on libgdx but i dont know how to do it. In the class an examples, setAligment is the option to do it, but in my android studio that option doesn´t exist, whent i try to put **selectBox.setAlignment(Align.right);** the setAlignment shows in red like the function doesn´t exist, the same problem with the **selectBox.getList().setAlignment(Align.right);** i´m using the 1.9.6 version of libgdx, i suppoused the version doesn´t have that functions anymore, but then how i can align the text?

Comment: show class where you use SelectBox including imports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setSelectedAlignment` in `SelectBox` and `setListAlignment` in `List` are added on 9-Apr-2017, there is a [PR](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/pull/3964/files#diff-15fb5fd25f569e78709b765fe97bd785) for the same.

I am sure you're using some older build of version 1.9.6, use [latest build](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/libgdx-nightly-20170706.zip) that deployed on 6-July-2107.

If you're using gradle in your project then you need re-download dependencies:

Generally, you can refresh dependencies in your cache with the command line option [--refresh-dependencies](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:cache_command_line_options). You can also delete the cached files under `~/.gradle/caches`. With the next build Gradle would attempt to download them again.

```
./gradlew build --refresh-dependencies
```

or use without build `./gradlew --refresh-dependencies`

<sub>You have to be noted that since gradle will try to download all dependency file, it takes time long.</sub>

---

Or you can use SNAPSHOT version, update snapshot version in `build.gradle` of your root project.

`gdxVersion = '1.9.7-SNAPSHOT'`

Comment: Thank you, i can´t with the refresh, even delete and redownload or create a project from zero doesn´t works, but with the gdxVersion = '1.9.7-SNAPSHOT' all works.